# Package Spacy - convert Nonetype output to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

```
test_document = nlp(sentences)
for ent in test_document.ents:
    output=print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

I am using spacy to recognize entities, but I will like to transform the output, which is NoneType, into a dictionary, where the key is the word (ent.text) and the value the label (ent.label_).

Comment: It sounds a bit odd. Where should the info come from, if what you have is None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(ent.text, ent.label_)` will return `None` and you are assigning this value to the `output` variable

You need to adjust your code, such that you store the entities correctly, as for example in a `dictionary`:

```
test_document = nlp(sentences)
dictionary = {}
for ent in test_document.ents:
    dictionary[ent.text] = ent.label
```